# About detectors after final round of surface code

Tags: stim, surface-code

Stim's surface code implementation example includes additional detectors after the final round to measure data qubits.

```
MX 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
DETECTOR(2, 0, 1) rec[-8] rec[-9] rec[-17] # L8 L15 Z14
DETECTOR(2, 4, 1) rec[-2] rec[-3] rec[-5] rec[-6] rec[-12] # d12 d19 d10 d17 Z18
DETECTOR(4, 2, 1) rec[-4] rec[-5] rec[-7] rec[-8] rec[-15] # d3 d10 L1 L8 Z9
DETECTOR(4, 6, 1) rec[-1] rec[-2] rec[-10] # d5 d12 Z13
```

Why are these detectors necessary? I understand that the decoder's role is to identify error locations based on measurements of the measurement qubits within each round, but would it also be acceptable to decode using measurements of the data qubits? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are these detectors necessary?

If you don't check that the data measurements agree with the stabilizer measurements, you wouldn't be comparing the data measurements to anything. If you're not comparing them to anything, you're not checking anything. You need to check things to correct errors.

> would it also be acceptable to decode using measurements of the data qubits?

I don't understand the question. This *is* decoding using the data qubit measurements. Do you mean using the data qubits but not referencing the stabilizer measurements at all? That won't work because without the stabilizer measurements you have no reference for what to expect from the data qubits.

If you try to declare detectors that only depend on the data measurements, you won't be able to decode it using matching anymore. Errors in the bulk will have four symptoms (flipping the two local bulk detectors and the two end-of-time data-only detectors) instead of two symptoms. Also, in situations more complex than a memory experiment, you'll find that these data-only detectors aren't actually deterministic because they rely on the data measurement basis at the end being the same as the data initialization basis at the start but in general computations that's not always true.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't fully understand the decoding of the surface code. In the last code cycle, it's acceptable for the superposition of data qubits to be disrupted, so I now understand that we can use the measured information of the data qubits for decoding.